# Вопрос по падежным формам

Tags: морфология

Как отличать падежные формы В. п. от И. п. во мн. ч.?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Во множественном числе у одушевленных существительных формы винительного совпадают с родительным, у неодушевленных - с именительным. Что тут надо отличать-то?

Comment: Как их отличать др от др, то есть как понять, сущ-е в В.п или в И.п, если слова одинаковые? Какие слова помощники подставлять?

Comment: Что вы имеете виду под одинаковыми словами? Может, вас интересует, когда дополнение стоит в винительном падеже, а когда в именительном?

Comment: Из Москвы я уехал давно, но мне часто снится она, ее шумные улицы, тихие переулочки. Вопрос улицы и переулочки это подлежащее или дополнение! Спасибо!

Comment: Никак не могу понять и хотела проверить падежами, если И.п то подлежащее, если В.п то дополнение. Помогите! Пожалуйста очень надо!

Comment: Дополнение - ему; улицы и переулочки, она - подлежащее. Вам уже ответили в другой теме.

Comment: Если ответили, надо дать ссылку - и закрыть вопрос. Я ответа не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отличить именительный от винительного, ставьте двойной вопрос

Из Москвы я уехал давно, но мне часто снится она, ее шумные улицы, тихие переулочки. **Кто?что?** -**она,улицы, переулочки** - однородные подлежащие.

В винительном было бы **КОГО? ЧТО?** (вижу)**её,улицы, переулочки**.

Comment: Людмила, Маша же не *падеж* просит отличить, а ***падежные формы*.** Это и ставит в тупик. Или, думаете, просто неудачно выразилась?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отличить В.п. от И.п. во множественном числе (они совпадают у неодушевленных существительных), поставьте на место существительного, которое надо проверить, одушевлённое существительное.

Например:
*мне часто снится она, ее шумные **улицы**, тихие **переулочки**.*

Заменяем слово улица и проулочек на одушевленное слово "лиса". В И.п. мн.ч. "лисы", в В.п. мн.ч. - "лис". Получаем:

*мне часто снится она, ее шумные **лисы**, тихие **лисы***.

В примере форма И.п., значит в изначальном примере у нас И.п.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отличить именительный от винительного, нужно посмотреть, кто совершает действие. Предмет, обозначаемый существительным в именительном падеже, всегда совершает действие. Например, Мама позвала дочь. Из контекста видно, что действие совершает мама, значит, это именительный падеж, подлежащее. А слово дочь стоит в винительном падеже, дополнение. Метод подстановки тоже помогает разобраться в этом вопросе. Слово "лиса", о котором упоминали выше, в именительном падеже всегда будет иметь окончание А, а в винительном падеже - окончание У.  Например. Мама позвала дочь - ЛисА позвала лисУ. Следовательно, мама-лисА - именительный падеж, подлежащее, а лисУ-дочь - винительный падеж, дополнение. Еще пример, Слышу звон бубенцов издалёка. 1) Смотрим, кто совершает действие. Явно не "звон", значит, это не именительный падеж, хотя и отвечает на вопрос "что?"; 2) Подставляем "лису". Слышу лисУ бубенцов издалёка. Окончание У указывает на винительный падеж. Все эти правила действуют и по отношению к словам, стоящим в форме множественного числа.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример, Из Москвы я уехал давно, но мне часто снится она, ее шумные улочки, тихие переулки. 1)Улочки и переулки совершают действие, так как именно они снятся; 2) подставляем "лису". Снится шумная лисА, тихая лисА. Окончание А указывает на именительный падеж. В родительном падеже слово "лиса" будет иметь окончание Ы. Нет (чего?) шумной лисЫ, тихой лисЫ.